# What's meant by Tesseract configs?

Tags: tesseract

I have these questions about Tesseract :

1* what's tesseract configs?

2* if traindata is avaliable for language (say :arabic), is that mean that it can OCR any font of the language? or just the fonts specified in the traindata ?

3* If i have poor results with tesseract, What should i do? make new traindata file with that font or what?

Comment: #2: The training data is for a specific font, but that doesn't restrict Tesseract from reading characters from other fonts. #3: That'll give you the best accuracy.

Comment: #1: The setting of various internal variables to modify Tesseract behavior. http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ControlParams